# How to register app as an launcher after installation

Tags: java, android, homescreen, android-launcher

I am building a custom launcher (home screen) for Android 4.0+. Now I face an issue which is that I need user to setup a few things before they can use it as a custom launcher. That means that after initial setup, I need to register my app as custom launcher through code instead of through the manifest file. How do I go about this? It's clearly possible since Yahoo Aviate can do just that.

Comment: Just Create a temp Activity than take some input and store in database and secand time check value stored in database r not if data inserted than open lancher outher wise open dumy activity on your app

Comment: It was my fault that I didn't say that I was developing Android custom launcher (home screen app), not a regular app. So what I meant was that I needed to register my app as a custom launcher through code instead of through AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I needed to register my app as a custom launcher through code instead of through AndroidManifest.xml file

That is not strictly possible. You have to have the `MAIN`/`HOME` `<intent-filter>` in the manifest.

You are welcome to have that activity be disabled initially, via `android:enabled="false"` on the `<activity>` element. Then, when you are ready for the home screen to be usable, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to make the activity be enabled, after which the user can choose to use it as their home screen.